# ENUM Alternate for displaying value

Tags: c#, enums

From my experience, Enums types are great for a list of names that correspond to values that make code more readable for developers.

I'm constantly resisting the temptation to write out the name of the ENUM to the user. For example

```
enum Days {Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
console.writeline(Days.Sat.ToString());
```

I know that Enums are not meant to be displayed to users.  My question is what is the next best alternative, I know I could use a dictionary of values, or a class/struct etc. Enums are just so easy, I'd like to know next easy alternate to display values to the user?

Comment: Please comment if your going to down vote my question, so I can at least have a chance to improve it.

Comment: There are numerous ways to skin this cat: resource files keyed on enum, attributes on the enum, a hard-coded switch statement, etc. There is no "golden way" to do it, they all make trade-offs.

Comment: you could use longer user-friendly names; I populate CBOs with Enum names all the time.  Sometimes using .ToString, sometimes harvesting the `Description`.

Comment: @Plutoniz The problem I have with that is that you can't use spaces in enums.

Comment: You can use a resource file keyed of the enum as Adam said, or a database-driven approach. Often there is more data needed than just the name; even with the simple "days of the week" example, you could want the index of the day, an "IsWeekend" flag, etc.

Comment: @TravisK But you could pass that into code that inserts spaces between casing differences. Numerous ways to solve this one.

Comment: yup, and that is when I use the `Description`  ("Monday" has no space though)

Comment: Thanks Using Descriptions is probably the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @TravisK Someone nominated this question for closure as "primarily opinion-based". That's likely to be the person who downvoted.

Comment: (Personally, I disagree on both counts. In any case, the close vote review is still in progress, but it looks like it's headed in favor of leaving open.)

Comment: @Adi Inbar Thanks for the explination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the 'Description' attribute:

```
private enum Days
{
    [Description("Saturday")]
    Sat,
    [Description("Sunday")]
    Sun,
    [Description("Monday")]
    Mon,
    [Description("Tuesday")]
    Tue,
    [Description("Wednesday")]
    Wed,
    [Description("Thursday")]
    Thu,
    [Description("It's Friday, Friday, gotta get down on Friday")]
    Fri
};

public static string DescribeEnum(Enum value)
{
    var field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
    var descriptionAttribute = (DescriptionAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
        field, typeof(DescriptionAttribute));

    return (descriptionAttribute == null)
               ? value.ToString()
               : descriptionAttribute.Description;
}

private static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(DescribeEnum(Days.Fri));
    // Output:
    // It's Friday, Friday, gotta get down on Friday
}
```